# compaction not triggered in rocksdb

Tags: rocksdb, lsm-tree

I have trouble triggering compactions during a bulk insert with HASHSKIPLIST memtable in rocksdb. I use PlainTable SST file format. Memtable size is set to 64MB and number of write buffers is 6. While inserting 200Million data, the number of level0 files goes around 80+ and i dont see compaction being triggered. I have configured level0 as follows,

level0_stop_writes_trigger=36

level0_slowdown_writes_trigger=20

level0_file_num_compaction_trigger=2

If i set the memtable as SKIPLIST, i can see compaction. Im not sure what prevents compaction in HashSkiplist. How to trigger it ?? Thanks in advance.